# replace number to words in right position in java

Tags: java

Actually I'm trying to replace number to words in the sentence that giving by user. This case date format; For example: `My birthday is on 16/6/2000 and I'm newbie to the java` --> ***become*** ---> `My birthday is on sixteenth july two thousand and I'm newbie to the java`

Here is code:

```
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any numbers: ");
        String nom = reader.nextLine(); // get input from user

        //checking contains that has "/" or not
        if(nom.contains("/")){
           String parts[] = nom.split("[/]"); 
           String part1 = parts[0]; //data before "/" will be stored in the first array
           String day[] = part1.split("\\s+");// split between space
           String get_day = day[day.length -1];// get last array

           String get_month = parts[1]; //data in the between of "/" will be stored in the second array

           String part3 = parts[2]; // data after "/" will be stored in the third array
           String year[] = part3.split("\\s+");// split between space
           String get_year = year[0];// get first array

           String s = NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_day)) + 
                      NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_month)) + 
                      NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_year));

           String con = nom.replaceAll("[0-9].*/[0-9].*/[0-].*", s); // replace number to word        
           System.out.println(con); // print the data already converted
        } else {....}
```

But the result that I have got is:

```
My birthday is on sixteenth july two thousand 

//"and I'm newbie to the java" is disappear [How to solve it]//
```

How to solve it. Actually I want to get value before and after of "/" slash and convert it to words and replace it as a original input from user.

What I have tried is:

```
String con = nom.replaceAll("[0-9].*/[0-9].*/[0-9999]", s); // a bit change [0-9].* to [0-9999]
```

But output become like this:

```
My birthday is on sixteenth july two thousand 000 and I'm newbie to the java
//after two thousand index "000" is appearing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex is wrong:

```
[0-9].*/[0-9].*/[0-].*
```

What it means:

```
[0-9] match a single number in the range between 0 and 9
.* matches any character (except newline) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
/ matches the character / literally
[0-9] match a single number in the range between 0 and 9
.* matches any character (except newline) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
/ matches the character / literally
[0-] match a single number in the list 0- literally
.* matches any character (except newline) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```

It should be:

```
[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Or, better:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

Comment: @ BackSlash Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below regex pattern to get all the numbers from String:

```
        String st = "My birthday is on 16/6/2000 and I'm newbie to the java, using since 2015";     
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
        while (m.find()) {
          System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```